# common table expression or subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following there are two queries,providing the same result , with the only difference that the first query is with a subquery and the second one is with a common table expression. The question is what is the "performance" difference between those two ways (subquery and CTE) ?

From what I have read CTE is better when you want to reuse the query but, apart from that I haven't read any other advantage or disadvantage between those two ways.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,tt.c1,tt.c2.tt.c3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.col1 as c1 ,t2.col2 as c2 ,t3.col3 as c3
            FROM table2 t2
            INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1= t3.col1
            WHERE t3.col1>100 ) tt ON t1.col1= tt.col1
```

---

```
;WITH CTE(
SELECT t2.col1 as c1 ,t2.col2 as c2 ,t3.col3 as c3
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.col1= t3.col1
WHERE t3.col1>100
)


SELECT col1,col2,col3,tt.c1,tt.c2.tt.c3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN CTE  tt ON t1.col1= tt.col1
```

Comment: Why not run them both and look at the execution plan? That is what is required to know what the performance differences would be.

Comment: Tagging 3 different database engines isn't going to help. Anyway, this question is far too broad.

Comment: There is no difference.  Nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 0):

In this context and with this usage, it's essentially the same.
You would use the CTE only to help readability.